# ¿Como implementar SharedPreferences en este código?

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo este código de arranque, el cual uso para activar una APP cuando se prende el celular. Hasta ahora me ha funcionado muy bien.

Ahora necesito colocar un SharedPreferences para modificar un par de parámetros al iniciar la APP cuando el celular se prende. El problema es que me genera un error y no se como solucionarlo.

Así tengo el código con el SharedPreferences incluido.

Gracias

```
public class AutoArranque extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent service = new Intent(context, inicio.class);
    context.startService(service);

    SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences( "configuracion", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("rebooted","S");
    editor.putString("control_1","S");
    editor.commit();

}
```

El error que se presenta es:

> El error que se genera al generar el APK, es el siguiente: Error:(25,
> 39) error: cannot find symbol method getSharedPreferences(String,int)

Comment: Y el error es...??

Comment: Importante revisar el LogCat y agrega el error que se muestra, el error incluso puede ser en el servicio, no veo problema en las preferencias.

Comment: Buen día @Jorgesys , gracias por responder. El error que se genera al generar el APK, es el siguiente: Error:(25, 39) error: cannot find symbol method getSharedPreferences(String,int)

Comment: Buen día @E.Betanzos , gracias por responder. El error que se genera al generar el APK, es el siguiente: Error:(25, 39) error: cannot find symbol method getSharedPreferences(String,int)

Comment: Ok Isabel , recuerda siempre agregar esta información al realizar tus preguntas, agregue una respuesta, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys buenas tardes, ¿le puedo hacer una pregunta?

Comment: Buenas tardes @Isabel Claro Isabel, ya la tienes hecha? o aquí?

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, la pregunta ya la hice pero no quede bien con la respuesta. La pregunta en resumen es: ¿Existe alguna forma de comprobar, si un procedimiento o clase ya se esta ejecutando? por ejemplo, quiero saber si ya se esta ejecutando formando_palabras(), para que no se inicialice en caso de que ya se este ejecutando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu error:

Error:(25, 39) error: cannot find symbol method getSharedPreferences(String,int)

indica que no puede encontrar el método, esto se debe a que necesitas el contexto para poder usar este método

Usa el contexto para acceder al método `context.getSharedPreferences( "configuracion", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );`

Este sería el código:

```
public class AutoArranque extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent service = new Intent(context, inicio.class);
    context.startService(service);

    SharedPreferences preferences= context.getSharedPreferences( "configuracion", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("rebooted","S");
    editor.putString("control_1","S");
    editor.commit();

}
```

Comment: mmmm, en el poco tiempo que llevo aprendiendo java, el manejo del CONTEXT siempre me a dado dificulta dado que no lo entiendo muy bien, entiendo el THIS, el cual se usa para hacer referencia al activity en el que se esta trabajando, pero el CONTEXT siempre me da dificultad y me pierdo. Gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: Disculpa mi atrevimiento, tengo dos preguntas, si me colaboras te agradecería mucho. 1. Mi proyecto lo estoy trabajando en Android Studio 2.2.3, ¿es muy complicado pasarse a la versión actual 4.1.1, si me paso mi proyecto se daña o se desbarata? Que me sugiere?   2. En Android studio yo genero mi APK para android y lo instalo en mi celular. ¿Existe alguna herramienta o forma de generar a partir de este código el APK o el instalador para IOS de apple? Gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: Con respecto a tus preguntas, me sorprende aún tengas usando la versión 2.2.3, en este caso te recomiendo crear un proyecto en 4.1.1 y agregar las clases, si no tienes mucha experiencia tal vez sea un poco difícil migrarlo. "¿Existe alguna herramienta o forma de generar a partir de este código el APK o el instalador para IOS de apple? " En este caso lo ideal es realizar un desarrollo nuevo no hay algo para convertir el .APK y  usarlo en un dispositivo iOS, te recomiendo crear un nuevo proyecto usando https://flutter.dev/

Comment: Ok gracias, voy a probar el flutter.dev, imagino que es como un ANDROID STUDIO para generar APK para IOS. gracias Saludos

Comment: @Isabel si Isabel de hecho tu desarrollo puede funcionar para ambas plataformas! :-)

Answer (score -2):

Asi es como edito SharedPreferences en mi aplicación

```
SharedPreferences preferencias = getSharedPreferences("Config", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferencias.edit();
editor.putString("estacion", estacion);
editor.putString("servidor", servidor);
editor.putString("basedatos", basedatos);
editor.putString("baseLocal", baseLocal);
editor.putString("baseServidor", baseServidor);
editor.putString("usuario", usuario);
editor.putString("contrasenna", contrasenna);
editor.putString("puerto", puerto);
editor.putString("almacen", almacen);
editor.commit();
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución es demasiado importante revises [answer] para realizar respuestas en el sitio, saludos.

Comment: Este codigo es exactamente igual al puesto en la pregunta. Como soluciona este codigo el problema de la pregunta?

Comment: Tiene razón, mil disculpas, para la otra pondre mas atención.